# Is there any way to delete files by a mask (*) on a remote system via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh

Is there any way to delete files by mask (*) on a remote system via SSH?

```
ssh -A -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@server1 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user2@server2 sudo rm -rf /folder/cache-*'
```

This command should delete all folders by mask cache-* on a remote server2. After execution, files aren't deleted.

If to execute this command locally on server2, files are deleted:

```
sudo rm -rf /folder/cache-*
```

Comment: Does user2 require a password to run as `sudo`?

Comment: No. This command works fine, for example:
ssh -A -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@server1 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user2@server2 sudo rm -rf /folder/cache-123'

Comment: The main problem, as I can see is that SSH doesn't correctly handle the * symbol.

Comment: Try replacing the `*` by `\*`.

Comment: I've tried \* and other variants. The result was the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys for your help. You are awesome and I didn't expect to meet so much enthusiasts.
I've also found a solution, a bit weird but still working.
So, I've created file on the target server delete.sh at /usr/local/bin/:

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/rm -rf $1
```

Then I execute a command:

```
ssh -A -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@SERVER1 "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user2@SERVER2 sudo /usr/local/bin/delete.sh /folder/cache-*"
```

As a result, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, that `*` is expanded on `server1`.
This should work:

```
ssh -A -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@server1 "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user2@server2 sudo bash -c 'rm -rf /folder/cache-*'"
```

Additionally, make sure that you do not need a password for `sudo` on `server2`.

*EDIT 1*:
If you have problems with globbing, use `shopt -s extglob:

```
ssh -A -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@server1 "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user2@server2 sudo bash -c 'shopt -s extglob; rm -rf /folder/cache-*'"
```

Comment: Hi, toydarian. I've tried this but unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: I updated the command to make sure bash is used and the `*` is expanded properly.

Comment: I think it's the right way to solve the problem, but I face an error:
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.

Comment: I guess, you have `extglob` off, see edit

Answer (score 0):

This sounds doable.  You should be able to do this with the appropriate number of backslashes.  You may also benefit by running a shell.

Recommended: to make things safer, don't run "rm".  Instead, run "echo rm".  That way, you can see what each command sees.

You're basically asking ssh to run ssh in order to run sudo in order to run rm.  A problem is that neither ssh, nor the other ssh, nor sudo, nor rm are likely to support expanding * into filenames.  That is done by a shell, and the shell on your local system is likely to want to expand based on local filenames.  So, run a shell on the remote system.

I'ven't the time to fully simulate this test at the moment, but something like:

> ssh -A -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@server1 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user2@server2 "sudo sh -c "echo rm -rf /folder/cache-*""'

(That ended with an asterisk, and then a backslash, and then an escaped quotation mark, and then a quotation mark, and then an apostrophe.)

Note #1: though, that sometimes I've had to use as many as eight backslashes to convert to a single one.  (I think that may have been when remotely using something involving Regex.  For a double-remote session, you might even need twice as many.)  I suggest trying up to 17.  (An odd backslash, like the 17th, will likely show up as a visible character.  So if there are two backslashes, that may suggest 16 were treated as one, and then one left over.  If there are 3, that may suggest that 8 were treated as one, and then one left over.)

So, something like this:

> ssh -A -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user1@server1 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user2@server2 "sudo sh -c \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"echo rm -rf /folder/cache-*\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\""'

Yes, blasting out way too many backslashes seems sloppier than carefully considering the reason for each need to double a backslash.  But I find that for one-time tasks like building a command, this often works.  Just throwing on the backslashes, and then reducing their number by one until a test ends up looking just right, is often faster than trying to analyze the situation enough to get it all perfect without guesswork.

Note #2:  I'm hoping you're using an ssh command line that lets you see the output.  I do notice the Linux tag.  But if your remote systems are Linux, and your local system is Windows using PuTTY which defaults to auto-closing, then you won't see the results of your echo command.  In that case, you'd either need to redirect output (which might itself be a bit of a pain regarding escaping characters on the right system), or flip a checkbox in PuTTY related to PuTTY's "auto-close on clean exit".

Note #3: Notice the changes I made other than adding backslashes.  First, I inserted "`sh -c`" into the mix.  Also, as a reminder to a prior note I brought up, realize I changed that to "`echo rm`".  Of course, once things look lovely, feel free to remove the characters "`echo` "